Python - Tapi3 incoming calls
I have this function that from online that works great to get the callerid etc of incoming calls using tapi 3 but that uses the call info interface which does not allow me to use the basic call controls to control the call, hold, unhold, transfer etc etc.
Is there a way to get from the call info or maybe the ITAddress to the ITBasicCallControl using win32com?
I understand i am doing this the hard way by using Python.
def handle_tapi_events():
    pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
    class TapiEvents(win32com.client.getevents(cls)):
        def OnEvent(self, ev1,ev2):
            constants = win32com.client.constants
            if ev1 == constants.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION:
                call = win32com.client.Dispatch(ev2).Call
                
                
                
                try:
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLEDIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_CALLEDIDNAME)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLEDIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_CALLEDIDNUMBER)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CONNECTEDIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNAME)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNAME)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNUMBER)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNAME", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNAME)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNUMBER", call, constants.CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNUMBER)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLEDPARTYFRIENDLYNAME", call, constants.CIS_CALLEDPARTYFRIENDLYNAME)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_COMMENT", call, constants.CIS_COMMENT)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_DISPLAYABLEADDRESS", call, constants.CIS_DISPLAYABLEADDRESS)
                   print_check_error(f"CIS_CALLINGPARTYID", call, constants.CIS_CALLINGPARTYID)
                except:
                   pass


These Microsoft samples show it from the TAPI3 side, but converting to python is outside of my expertise ;-)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tapi/make-a-call
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tapi/receive-a-call

Yeah no idea where to look next to be fair, it grabs the caller id of the incoming call, and allows me to call them.
But i can't do anything with the call when they ring me.
